# Logstash parse date/time

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following I'm trying to parse with GROK:

`Hello|STATSTIME=20-AUG-15 12.20.03.051000 PM|World`

I can parse the first bunch of it with GROK like so:

`match => ["message","%{WORD:FW}\|STATSTIME=%{MONTHDAY:MDAY}-%{WORD:MON}-%{INT:YY} %{INT:HH}"]`

Anything further than that gives me an error.  I can't figure out how to quote the : character, : does not work and %{TIME:time} does not work.  I'd like to be able to get the whole thing as a timestamp, but can't get it broken up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your example uses "." (period) to separate hour/min/sec, but your narrative talks about ":" (colon).  Which is it?

Comment: Jesus, I saw a `:` and that's what I kept doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to debug grok expressions

The time format is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3by5.png)

To parse **12.20.03.051000**

```
%{INT:hour}.%{INT:min}.%{INT:sec}.%{INT:ms}
```

Output will be something like this

```
{
"hour": [
      [
      "12"
      ]
 ],
"min": [
     [
      "20"
     ]
 ],
"sec": [
    [
     "03"
    ]
],
"ms": [
    [
   "051000"
    ]
 ]
}
```